# How to check authenticity of iOS device

Tags: ios

I have an app-server process that needs to check if the device making a request is an actual iOS device.  I used to do this by taking advantage of push notifications.  The user first authorizes push.  Each time the user makes a specific type of request, I push a code to that device with which the app uses to make a second "authenticated" request to the app server.  That additional channel of going through APNS would, in a sense, prove the authenticity of the requester's device.  This makes it difficult for a person to spoof the request because they would not be able to receive the push notification with the needed code.

Recently though Apple started enforcing the rule that apps cannot require the user to accept push notifications in order to use the app, even though we do not use push notifications for alerts.

Is there any comparable way for my app server to check with Apple that a request is coming from my app on an actual iOS device?  Or is this an unrealistic expectation to be able to determine this.

Comment: There is none, but you can use HTTPS to difficult (in most cases prevent) sniffing. You can also make you server generate an identifier/token for each device that doesn't have one, and make that device store it locally, or preferably on its keychain. Then the device informs the token via HTTPS and your server is able to to identify the device. I believe this should solve your concern. Does it help?

Comment: Is your real goal to ensure a request coming to your server is really coming from your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find the article now, but some guys managed to register raspberry pi as a iOS device and receive push notifications via wifi... that I believe would be concrete proof that not even your first "2 way authentication" is really safe...

Now, directly answering, NO, there's no way for your app server to check if the request did come from a iOS device because all info in a TCP/UDP package is 100% "spoofable"...

Comment: Which is why I posted my comment below the question. Most likely, checking for an iOS device is the wrong approach. The approach should be to authenticate that the request is coming from a specific app and there are proper solutions to that.